# Debug real time on arm (RTKLIB)

Tags: debugging, arm, raspberry-pi2, cortex-a

I am currently working on [RTKLIB](https://github.com/tomojitakasu/RTKLIB)

The software runs and gives good results on Windows and Linux on a x64.
On Arm (raspberry pi 2), position calculations are not good and I expect it is because the library doesn't have any safety for casts, types that can be used on Arm.

The question is: Is there a way to debug such a giant library fast knowing it's a realtime application ?

EDIT: Issue comes from the data of GLONASS satellites having jumps in calculations

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running the tests included in the library?  These should be the first step to finding out if there's some code generation issue due to the platform, though who knows how much coverage they have.  A quick search on "RTKLIB raspberry pi" brings up at least a few hits and examples and nobody was complaining it wasn't working so maybe your issue is elsewhere?

Comment: I edited my post. Issue comes from the data of GLONASS satellites having jumps in calculations. No one made it work with those ones. People only use GPS (and I want to use GPS+GLONASS)